# Is it possible to reference existing cache in Mybatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

```
  <mapper namespace="src.main.domain.EqMapper">
                  <cache
                  eviction="FIFO"
                  size="512"
                  readOnly="true"/>

    <select id="getStoreIdAndEqId"  resultType="String" flushCache="false" useCache="true">
                 select count(author) from blog
        </select>
  <select id="getWholeData"  resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" flushCache="false" useCache="true">
                 select * from blog
        </select>
  </mapper>
```

Scenario : 1st I call `getWholeData` method which brings the complete data at a time. For example at that time the result of  `select count(author) from blog` is 20 in real DB. And then I call `getStoreIdAndEqId` after 10 mins then I expect to get data as 20 as I have loaded whole data the 1st time which is not happening while `getWholeData` has 20 records `getStoreIdAndEqId` returns new data may be 25 at that time no matter it remains in cache then after. Is it not possible that when I call `getStoreIdAndEqId` anywhere for the 1st it should not query db instead it should query from `getWholeData` cache and return 20 instead of new 25.